# Do not load the plugin for multiple occurrences in WordPress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am using the code below to disable a plugin for specific URL path but I have more paths that I would like add. For example, I like to disable the plugin for and URL that contains /xxxx/, /xxxx1/, /xxxx2/, /xxxx3/,/xxxx4/.

How do I include all other 4 paths in the code below?

```php
// Do not load the plugin if the 404 URL starts with '/xxxx/'
add_filter('wp404arsp/init', 'my_404_no_init2', 10, 2);

function my_404_no_init2($init, $query){

    // Print $query array for more request context

    if (preg_match('#/xxxx/(.+?)/?$#i', $query['request']['url']))
        $init = false;

    return $init;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for file 1-4 :
change `preg_match` pattern to :

```
'#/xxxx{1-4}*/(.+?)/?$#i'
```